# Do all google APIs use the same oauth2 access tokens?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Can I use the same Oauth2 access tokens for all google APIS or are they API specific? IE. different access tokens for Google Maps and Youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens are specific to the list of scopes used when requesting them. If you want to combine scopes from different services, then that's fine. I can't confirm that this applies to every single Google API, as there may be some which still run through older infrastructure. I suggest you use the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to test your specific combinations.